# Wrong dense layer output shape after moving from TF 1.12 to 1.10

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, amazon-sagemaker

I'm migrating from Tensorflow 1.12 to Tensorflow 1.10 (Collaboratory -> AWS sagemaker), the code seems to be working fine in Tensorflow 1.12 but in 1.10 i get an error `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (52692,)`

Input example - strings with no whitespaces:

```
["testAbc", "aaDD", "roam"]
```

which I preprocess by changing small letters into 1, capital letters 2, digits - 3, '-' - 4, '_' - 5 and padding so they are equal length with 0s

and 4 labels a - 0, b - 1, c - 2, d - 3

Assuming max length for each word is 10 (in my code it's 20):

features - [[1 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 0 0][1 1 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0][1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]]

labels - [1, 1, 2, 3]

expected output: [a: 0%, b: 0%, c: 1%, d: 99%] (example)

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(
    keras.layers.Embedding(6, 8, input_length=maxFeatureLen))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(12))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.softmax))
model.compile(tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001), loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy")
model.fit(train["featuresVec"],
            train["labelsVec"],
            epochs=1,
            verbose=1,
            callbacks=[],
            validation_data=(evale["featuresVec"], evale["labelsVec"],),
            validation_steps=evale["count"],
            steps_per_epoch=train["count"])
```

Shapes of train and evale - 2D arrays

```
train["featuresVec"]=
[[1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]

evale["featuresVec"]=
[[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]

train["labelsVec"] = [1 0 0 0 2]
evale["labelsVec"] = [0 1 1 1 1]
```

Shapes:

```
train["featuresVec"] = [52692, 20]
evale["featuresVec"] = [28916, 20]
train["labelsVec"] = [52692]
evale["labelsVec"] = [28916]
```

Comment: What are the shapes of train["featuresVec"] and train["labelsVec"] ?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I've updated the question with values from code

Comment: Yes but i asked about the shapes only. You can now see that the data doesn't have the right format.

Comment: I also asked about train["labelsVec"]

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro train=[52692, 20] and eval=[28916, 20] - Sorry, I still don't see the data being in the wrong format

Comment: train["labelsVec"] =[52692]
evale["labelsVec"]=[28916]

Comment: train["labelsVec"] has the wrong shape, it looks like you didn't one-hot encode it.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro My understanding was that I can use embedding instead of one-hot encoding and as I said in the post it works fine in tensorflow 1.12 on collaboratory.

Comment: Ah wait, the sparse cross entropy loss does the one-hot encoding, can you try making the labels array (52692, 1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your labels vector needs to be of shape `(batch_size, 1)` instead of just `(batch_size,)`.

**Note:** Since you are using `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` as loss function instead of `categorical_crossentropy`, it is correct to not one-hot encode the labels.

Comment: So I've tried just wrapping labels into another [] - to create shape (size,1) but I'm still getting 
Error when checking target: expected dense to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (52692,)

Comment: I think that you are creating shape (1, size) this way instead of (size, 1). Maybe try with a reshape?